# How to build predicate for a List in spring queryDSL?

Tags: spring-data-jpa, querydsl

```
    Service.java

    private String sid;
    private String serviceName;
    private List<Feature> feature;

    Feature.java

    private Long id;
    private String featureName;
```

I build predicates like below

```
     import com.querydsl.core.BooleanBuilder;
     import com.querydsl.core.types.Predicate;

     BooleanBuilder booleanBuilder = new BooleanBuilder();
     booleanBuilder.and(QService.service.id.eq(id));
     booleanBuilder.and(QFeature.feature.usoc.eq(featureUsoc));

     Predicate predicate = booleanBuilder;

     serviceRepository.findAll(predicate);
```

When I query the repo, I get below error

```
nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.QueryException: illegal attempt to dereference collection [{synthetic-alias}{non-qualified-property-ref}feature] with element property reference [featureName] [select service
from com.ws.app.model.Service service
where service.id = ?2 and feature.featureName = ?3]]
```

How to build predicate query for a variable in entity if it is of type List?

Answer (score 1):

You would need a JOIN or a subquery to the correlated path:

```java
query().from(QService.service)
    .where(QService.service.id.eq(id))
    .where(query().from(QService.service.feature, QFeature.feature)
          .where(QFeature.feature.usoc.eq(featureUsoc))
          .exists())
    .fetch()
```

Join:

```java
query().from(QService.service)
    .innerJoin(QService.service.feature, QFeature.feature)
    .on(QFeature.feature.usoc.eq(featureUsoc))
    .where(QService.service.id.eq(id))
    .fetch()
```

Comment: Here query() means JPAQuery or JPASubQuery ? Lot of options are there, can you please give me the import for that ?

Comment: Could be a `JPAQuery`. Since QueryDSL 4 you can't directly instantiate `JPASubQuery` and should just use `JPAQuery` for subqueries.

Comment: I added , ```JPAQuery jpaQuery = new JPAQuery();
            QService service = QService.service;
            QFeature feature = QFeature.feature;
            jpaQuery.from(QService.service)
                    .innerJoin(QService.service.feature, QFeature.feature)
                    .on(QFeature.feature.usoc.eq(featureUsoc));

            booleanBuilder.and(service.feature.any().eq(jpaQuery));``` Now I get "Subquery returned more than 1 value." error, I need to put IN in that but don't know how to apply IN.

Comment: fixed "Subquery returned more than 1 value." by changing booleanBuilder.and(service.feature.any().in(jpaQuery));, Here I add IN instead of eq

Comment: I'd avoid `any`. It doesn't create the query you likely want. Try `booleanBuilder.and(QService.service.feature.in(JPAExpressions.selectFrom(QFeature.feature).where(QFeature.feature.usoc.eq(featureUsoc))`

Unfortunately Spring Data abstracts QueryDSL and JPA away here. You need to know what you're dealing with to properly write queries like these. I suggest writing your query in QueryDSL/JPQL first and only then transform it to Spring Data, when you get a feeling of what you're dealing with.